# Using awk, group CIDR with ports, and count all ports with respective CIDR

Tags: awk, data-manipulation

I have a file containing a CIDR address and port on each line:

```
192.168.1.0/24 3306  
192.168.1.0/24 55982  
10.10.10.0/24 5800  
10.10.10.0/24 39690  
10.10.10.0/24 50112  
192.168.1.0/24 3308  
192.168.1.0/24 3312  
192.168.1.0/24 3316
```

Using GNU Awk 4.1.4 (on a Linux system), the initial idea was to put all ports on one line grouped by CIDR address, so this did it:

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] ? a[$1]","$2 : $2} END {for (j in a) {print j" over ports: "a[j]}}' file

192.168.1.0/24 over ports: 3306,3308,3312,3316,55982  
10.10.10.0/24 over ports: 5800,39690,50112
```

**I also wanted to add a count for how many ports there were per CIDR address to get this result:**

```
192.168.1.0/24 over 5 ports: 3306,3308,3312,3316,55982  
10.10.10.0/24 over 3 ports: 5800,39690,50112
```

I've tried putting values into arrays and printing out the key, but the count always comes out to 2.

```
awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] ? a[$1]","$2 : $2} {h[$1]++;} END {for (i in h) for (j in a) {print j" over "h[i]" ports: "a[j]}}' file

192.168.1.0/24 over 2 ports: 3306,3308,3312,3316,55982  
10.10.10.0/24 over 2 ports: 5800,39690,50112
```

I'm willing to do other things besides awk, but it's preferable due to the files with the CIDR/ports are millions of lines, and awk is fast. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without multi-dim arrays

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] "," $2:$2; c[$1]++} 
    END{for(k in a) print k,"over " c[k] " ports:",a[k]}' file

10.10.10.0/24 over 3 ports: 5800,39690,50112
192.168.1.0/24 over 5 ports: 3306,55982,3308,3312,3316
```

Comment: This works very fast for files under 25MB. When the files get bigger than that, it starts to get slow. When I use andreatsh answer, it works better for bigger files but doesn't really make a big difference with smaller ones.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution with `awk`:

```
awk '{ z[$1][++count[$1]]; s[$2]=$1; } 
       END {
         for (i in z)
         { 
           printf( i" over "count[i]" ports: " );
           c=0;
           # print ports according to the key value
           # and the requested format, i.e. port1,port2,...
           for (j in s)
             if(s[j]==i)
                 # we don't want a comma at the end of the line,
                 # after the last port we put a newline
                 if (c<count[i]-1)
                 { 
                   printf(j","); 
                   c++;
                 }
                 else printf(j"\n")
         }
       } 
}' file
```

And its output:

```
10.10.10.0/24 over 3 ports: 5800,39690,50112
192.168.1.0/24 over 5 ports: 3306,3308,3312,3316,55982
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{cnts[$1]++; ports[$1]=($1 in ports ? ports[$1] "," : "") $2}
       END{for (ip in ports) print ip, "over", cnts[ip], "ports:", ports[ip]}' file
10.10.10.0/24 over 3 ports: 5800,39690,50112
192.168.1.0/24 over 5 ports: 3306,55982,3308,3312,3316
```